# Troubleshoot VirtualBox Linux Ubuntu guest access from Windows host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I'm running VirtualBox on a Windows 7 Host, with an Ubuntu Linux guest OS.

I'm trying to set up Samba on Linux to access a folder (/home/user) from the Windows host as a share - which I believe SHOULD be possible, but having trouble getting it to work. I am aware of the Share Folder option of VirtualBox but I specifically need to get this done using Samba.

I installed Samba (`apt-get install samba sambafs`) and set up `/etc/smbd.conf` with a share

```
[usershare]
path = /home/user
read only = no
browseable = yes
```

Not worried about securing it by user just yet - want to get it working first.

I set up *two* network adapters in VirtualBox - one NAT so I can get to the Internet for apt-get and stuff, one Host-Only hoping that will let me access the Ubuntu guest from the host only.  (Hence the lack of immediate concern over user-level security.)

Now, I can see an IP for the Host-only network in Windows, and tried to access it in the Windows Explorer - a blank window comes up and I don't see anything.  The IP looks like 169.254.127.xxx.  If I put in `\\169.254.127.xxx\usershare` it hangs for a while and fails.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Is this likely a networking config problem or a Samba problem?

Comment: I have kind of an odd use case.  I have a specific reason why I want to access the guest OS as a share in Windows.  If I just wanted to copy files back and forth, you're right, VirtualBox shared folder is *WAY* easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out.

There were a few gaps in my understanding:

*Samba setup*

- I realized that Samba users require their own authentication are not necessarily the same as UNIX usernames/passwords.  So I created account with `smbpasswd`.
- I then confirmed that Samba setup was correct by mounting locally within the VM using `smbmount`, e.g., `smbmount //localhost/share /mnt/test -o user=testuser,pass=password`

*Virtualbox setup*

- I ended up wtih two NIC's on my VM - eth0 is default NAT adapter, then new eth1 is host-only
- In the VM, I gave eth1 a static IP address on the same subnet as the host-only network in VirtualBox File>Preferences>Network menu.  The key I was missing is that the VM needs a  DIFFERENT IP address than the host-only adapter on the host side.  So the host-only adapter in VirtualBox is on 192.168.100.1, the static IP for Ubuntu guest is 192.168.100.2 (for example).
- Finally, once this was set up, I could see the Samba share under `\\192.168.100.2\share\`