# Access Samba share running in VirtualBox with Alpine Linux guest from Windows 10 host in domain

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, samba, windows-domain, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run a Samba server installed in an Alpine Linux 3.7.0(Vanilla) inside VirtualBox and trying to access that from my Windows 10 host which is part of a domain. Here are the links that I tried to use to mitigate the problem but neither of them worked, hence I'm forced to ask this question again.

- [Using Samba to share a folder from a Linux guest with a Windows host in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/258026/using-samba-to-share-a-folder-from-a-linux-guest-with-a-windows-host-in-virtualb)
- [Troubleshoot VirtualBox Linux Ubuntu guest access from Windows host](https://superuser.com/questions/562923/troubleshoot-virtualbox-linux-ubuntu-guest-access-from-windows-host?rq=1)
- [Access Samba share from Windows 10 in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1190025/access-samba-share-from-windows-10-in-virtualbox?rq=1)

My Windows 10 box is part of a domain called `XX`. My Windows domain username is `XX\SuperCoolUser`.

I've installed Samba with the help of this [article](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_samba-server).

I've tried both

- `smbpasswd -a root`
- `adduser SuperCoolUser` and then `smbpasswd -a SuperCoolUser`

Both don't work.

#### /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   workgroup = XX
   server string = Samba Server %v
   netbios name = dev-1
   security = user
   map to guest = bad user
   dns proxy = no
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

[storage]
   path = /media/storage
   browsable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
```

#### /etc/samba/smbusers -

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
root = SuperCoolUser
```

When I run `smbclient -L localhost -U%` then this the output

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
storage         Disk
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server 4.7.3)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

Server               Comment
---------            -------

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
XX                   DEV-1
```

My virtual machine has two adapters

- Bridged(DHCP) for internet
- Host-only(Static) for SSH and file sharing(Samba)

Note: I'm able to `ssh` into the machine and run commands, so its network visible.

---

### Edit

If I run the command `smbclient -L 192.168.56.131 -U samba@samba` where `samba` is the `foo` user.

I get the following output

```
Enter samba@samba's password:

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
storage         Disk
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server 4.8.2)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

Server               Comment
---------            -------

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
XX                   DEV-1
```

Notice the server section is empty. Does that mean my service is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your given structure, but modified a bit:

- in *smbusers* i'm not using **root** for user mapping, but a simple local user **foo**:

  - `foo = SuperCoolUser`
- in *smb.conf* `guest ok = no` (to prevent invalid users from accessing the share).

I'm able to access the share from Windows host with following steps:

1. on Linux guest create the user **foo** (if not already created)

   - `adduser foo` (i.e. password "bar")
2. on Linux guest create samba user with same name and password as linux user:

   - `smbpasswd -a foo` (password "bar")
   - `pdbedit -L` (checking if foo was created successfully)
3. on Windows host open cmd and run:

   - `net use Z: \\192.168.56.200\storage /user:SuperCoolUser /persistent:no`
   - as password input "bar"
   - message: "The command completed successfully"

Now you can list files on your share with `dir Z:`

Comment: When you say `foo = SuperCoolUser` do you mean the user that I use to login to windows?

Comment: I'm getting this error sadly from windows `System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.`

Comment: did you replace my ip address with the address of your linux guest?

Comment: Yeah I did. Lol.

Comment: the error 53 is not related to samba. you told the TCP connection from host to guest is all right. To make it sure, you can try to test it with i.e. Powershell command: `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.56.200 -Port 445 -InformationLevel "Detailed"`

Comment: You are right. The ports `445, 139` are blocked from domain administrators. Is there a way to use a different port?

Comment: On the linux guest you can select what port the samba server uses, but you can't force windows to access samba shares on ports different than 445 or 139.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At least you've let me identify the actual issue.